# Combining multiple csv files into one using java?

Tags: java, csv

I need a robust method that would combine multiple CSV files, taking into account the newline characters etc. Please help me with it and provide some code if possible.

Or at least help me with what all scenarios should I expect when combining them.

regards

Comment: Do you have an existing code to work with?

Comment: You can check [csv-merger](https://github.com/riyadparvez/csv-merger) github project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you're on a Unix based machine (Linux or OSX) you could use `cat` from the terminal to concatenate the files together.

If you absolutely want to use Java, this forum [post](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=147387) covers the topic and provides example code.

Also, this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307072/how-to-merge-csv-files-in-java) covered this very topic.

Comment: hey ryan, the forum post is exactly what i was looking for.. The stckoverflow post was a bit vague and did not show up in results when i searched for.. thanks

Comment: Any reason why I got a down vote? Would appreciate the feedback so I can continue to improve my answers here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to parse the data: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

1) I would parse in each csv into a string array for each line. Compare the initial first lines of each array using a .equals or compareto to make sure you're dealing with the same CSV, you can set this as a check in the first line of the parser, then throw out if they're not of the same type.

Once that's done you can, delete the first lines of all the arrays expect the first array then merge them together, then write a sort method to the data then print to a file.

2) Even easier, take all the CSVs, scan in their first lines, compare them, if they're the same, scan the entire CSV's into multiple string arrays, merge, then using the File class write the array's to the file.csv.

Another CSV parse: http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html

Answer (score 0):

Read them in separately, output them into one file. You can also add some code that checks if the records from the two csv files have the same number of columns, otherwise error.

This isn't really a Java-specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

In continuation with user453441's answer, also check for the separator. Many times 'Comma' Separated values are in fact - (because of some business conditions like address line can contain a comma) - separated by different delimiter(s).

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] headers = null;
String firstFile = "/path/to/firstFile.dat";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(firstFile));

if (scanner.hasNextLine())
    headers[] = scanner.nextLine().split(",");

scanner.close();

Iterator<File> iterFiles = listOfFilesToBeMerged.iterator();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(firstFile, true));

while (iterFiles.hasNext()) {
  File nextFile = iterFiles.next();
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nextFile));

  String line = null;
  String[] firstLine = null;
  if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    firstLine = line.split(",");

  if (!Arrays.equals (headers, firstLine))
    throw new FileMergeException("Header mis-match between CSV files: '" +
              firstFile + "' and '" + nextFile.getAbsolutePath());

  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    writer.write(line);
    writer.newLine();
  }

  reader.close();
}
writer.close();
```