# How to merge multiple csv files into a single csv files

Tags: java, csv, join, merge

I've a requirement where I need to merge multiple CSV files into a single csv file.
I tried Googling and got some info on CSVWriter or SuperCSV but I couldn't make out.

All the CSV files will contain the same columns / headers.

For better understanding:

I'm fetching 10,000 records from Database and I'm creating 10 csv files. (`MyCSV_1-1000.csv`, `MyCSV_1001-2000.csv`, `MyCSV_2001-3000` and so on.)
Each csv file containing 1,000 records. Now I need to merge all these csv files in to the first CSV so that `MyCSV_1-1000.csv` will contain all the records i.e. 1-10,000 (whereas before merging it contains only 1-1,000 records only).

Can someone help me on this.

I would like to do this in Java or any other Java supporting utility / framework.

Comment: CSV files are just regular files, just use normal Java I/O libraries to merge them.

Comment: Please have a look 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307072/how-to-merge-csv-files-in-java

Answer (score 4):

Merging records from multiple csv files into one is simple. If multiple csv files are on the same directory, you can execute the below command from the cmd.

```
D:\Files>copy *.csv Merged.csv
```

This will create a Merged.csv file into the same directory, and will have records from all the csv's.

Comment: More info on the solution here https://www.live2tech.com/merge-multiple-csv-files-combine-one-large-csv-file/

Answer (score 0):

Programming languages can be leveraged depending on the goal/problem one has at hand.

Assuming that you need to clean the datasets before the merge, `Python` has really good libraries, and I would suggest you to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

If the datasets have the same structure, create a for loop to do things like:

• Removing unnecessary rows

```
df.drop(df.index[[0,1,2]]) #Removing the first 3 rows
```

• Transpose the dataframe

```
transpose_dataframe = df.transpose()
```

• And more.

Once the cleaning process is complete, for the merge, one can also use Python. In my case, Maverick's answer generated some funny characters and didn't merge properly, so I have used the following:

```
import os
import csv, glob


Dir = r"C:\Users\name\Desktop\DataDirectory"
Avg_Dir = r"C:\Users\name\Desktop\Output"

csv_file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(Dir, '*.csv'))

print (csv_file_list)

with open(os.path.join(Avg_Dir, 'Output.csv'), 'w', newline='') as f:

    wf = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    
    for files in csv_file_list:
        with open(files, 'r') as r:
            next(r) # SKIP HEADERS
            rr = csv.reader(r)
            for row in rr:
                wf.writerow(row)
```